# Magento2 2.1.5 Cronjob doesn't get executed. ID always 0

Tags: magento2, cron, magento2.1.5

My magento cronjob stopped working. It gets executed from system. Checked that in the logs. But magento just shedules the cronjobs and don't execute them. Also the schedule_id of the cronjobs is always 0. Manually run the cron task gives me an execption. See images from cli and database. 
What could cause this issue ? And how to fix?

PHP 7 on ubuntu
Magento 2.1.5

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

As far as I can see this is an open issue for Magento2.x in github.
https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/5836

There are some solutions that some people suggest in the above link such as truncating the `cron_schedule` table - but I can't be certain as to whether this will work.

Answer (score 0):

your `cron_schedule` table has missing index key.
you need to run

```
ALTER TABLE `cron_schedule`
  ADD PRIMARY KEY (`schedule_id`),
  ADD KEY `CRON_SCHEDULE_JOB_CODE` (`job_code`),
  ADD KEY `CRON_SCHEDULE_SCHEDULED_AT_STATUS` (`scheduled_at`,`status`);
ALTER TABLE `cron_schedule`
  MODIFY `schedule_id` int(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT COMMENT 'Schedule Id';
```

https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/21523